# Adding a value to the Array inside a while loop

Tags: c#, fibonacci

I am making a program to run Fibonacci series. I have created 2 array.

1. 1st array holds only 0, 1  (Array Name :- int[] arr)
2. 2nd array holds other values eg: 1, 2, 3, 5..........etc ( Array Name:- int[] numbers)

I am using while loop to get the febonacci series and storing it in a 2nd array called int[] numbers.

after getting value using while loop, I am joing both the arrays using

```
int[] final = arr.Concat(number).ToArray();
```

At last, I have used foreach loop to add the febonacci series into the listbox.

The problem I have is that, I cannot able to concat both the arrays. I tried to assign number array at the top of the while loop. so that number variable will be accessible outside the while loop. But I am getting a error.

See the code below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 0;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(q1input.Text))
    {
        int value;
        if (int.TryParse(q1input.Text, out value))
        {
            int[] arr = {x, y };

            while (z < value)
            {
                z = x + y;
                int[] number = {z};
                x = y;
                y = z;
            }
            int[] final = arr.Concat(number).ToArray();
            foreach (int num in final)
            {
                q2listbox.Items.Add(num);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("It is not a numeric value");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: Can you explain `java` and `c++` tags of question?

Comment: sorry for the wrong tag. I am new to the stackoverflow. I thought I will get help fast if tag more.

Comment: wrong, you'll get help if you tag correct instead

Comment: ok. And this is not a homework. Just practising the C# with some internet tasks.

Answer (score 1):

```
                List<int> number = new List<int>();

                while (z < value)
                {
                    z = x + y;
                    number.Add(z);
                    x = y;
                    y = z;

                }
                int[] final = arr.Concat(number).ToArray();
```

Comment: Any explanation will help the OP some more. SO is not about 'fastest-answer-wins-the-price'

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you *separate your concerns*: computing a Fibonacci sequence should be separated from your user interface code.

Part of your problem is that you're working with arrays (fixed length) in C# building something that adjustable in length. [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a better data structure for your purposes. Despite its misleading name, it is an adjustable-length array rather than an actual list in the computer science sense.

Generating a Fibonacci sequence isn't as complicated as you're making it. This implementation:

```
public int[] FibonacciSequence( int x1 , int x2 , int upperBound )
{
  if ( x1 < 0 ) throw new ArgumentException("x1 can't be negative") ;
  if ( x2 < 0 ) throw new ArgumentException("x2 can't be negative") ;
  if ( x1 == 0 && x2 == 0 ) throw new ArgumentException("x1 and x2 can't both be zero.") ;

  List<int> values = new List<int>() ; // use List<int>, since we don't know the length in advance

  values.Add(x1) ; // the first 2 elements are given
  values.Add(x2) ;

  // the remaining elements are computed by summing the previous two elements and shifting.
  for ( int x = x1+x2 ; x > 0 && x < upperBound ; x = x1+x2 )
  {

     // add the new value to the list of values
    values.Add(x) ;

    x1 = x2 ; // x1 receives x2 (with the current x1 shifting off into oblivion
    x2 = x  ; // x2 receives x

  }

  int[] sequence = values.ToArray() ;
  return sequence ;
}
```

There's no rule, just convention, that a Fibonacci sequence starts with [0,1] or [1,1]. You can then invoke this function with your desired seeds, thus:

```
int[] fibonacci = FibonacciSequence(1,1,int.MaxValue) ;
```

The cool thing about a Fibonacci sequence is that regardless of the seed values, the further out you go in the sequence, the ratio of any two adjacent values converges towards *phi*, the Golden Mean.

Even easier is to use some of LINQ's functionality-cum-magick. Using that, your Fibonnaci sequence becomes even simpler:

```
public IEnumerable<int> FibinacciSequence( int x1 , int x2 )
{
  yield return x1 ;
  yield return x2 ;

  for ( int x = x1+x2 ; x > 0 && x < int.MaxValue ; x = x1+x2 )
  {
    yield return x ;
    x1 = x2 ;
    x2 = x  ;
  }
}
```

And its usage becomes something like:

```
int[] sequence = FibonacciSequence(1,1)
                 .TakeWhile( x => x < upperBound )
                 .ToArray()
                 ;
```

You can even skip the '`ToArray()` bit and simply say something like

```
foreach ( int value in FibonacciSequence(1,1).TakeWhile( x => x < upperBound ) )
{
  q2listbox.Items.Add( value ) ;
}
```

which will evaluate the sequence in a lazy manner as you add each value to your list box.

Comment: oh my. int.MaxValue... don't try this at home ;-)

Comment: `x` should be `long` if you're going to allow `upperBound = int.MaxValue`.

Comment: @DourHighArch, true. but a detail in this case